# Ionic 4 upgraded Node from v12 to Node v14

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, build, ionic4, node-modules

Hi guys l really need your help, l upgraded my node v12 to node v14 on my windows 10. Im having issues with my existing App build on ionic 4 type angular.  I failing to build the App.

I have tried npm update and npm install lm getting a lot of errors  of modules not found.

Is there a quick way of resolving this that doesn't involve creating a new project

Comment: What are the errors? Did you delete your node_modules folder and re install?

Comment: I havent deleted the node_modules folder yet 
below are the rrors
E:\ionic-docs\club790businessdirectory>ionic serve
> ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
[ng] chunk {} 0.js, 0.js.map () 30.4 kB  [rendered]
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/aws-sign2/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\ionic-docs\club790businessdirectory\node_modules\aws-sign2'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/aws4/aws4.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\ionic-docs\club790businessdirectory\node_modules\aws4'

Comment: Try deleting the node_modules and re-installing them. If that also doesn't work, try to upgrade your ionic-angular project to node-v14. Then install the node_modules again. That should resolve this issue.

Comment: Let me try that . Thank you very much